# java, use dictionary for zip?

Tags: java, zip

Hi I have source code from a program ,and when I test in NetBeans there is and error in import:

```
java.util.Dict;
```

Can anybody help me, please?

```
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Dict;
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a class called `Dict`. There is however a `Dictionary` class. Please check the API docs.